# Drawing rectangle in HTML 2.0

Tags: html

I am working in a project. I need to create a simple page with some writings and rectangles. However, the system that I am working on is an old one and I have been told that the system does not support the HTML 3 and upper versions' commands. Before this warning, I tried some methods like:

`<div style="width:20px;height:25px;border:1px solid #000"></div>`

It worked just fine when I converted the txt file to html and run it. However, rectangles did not shown on the system, so learning to draw a rectangle in HTML 2.0 would be enough I think, and I have also told that I cannot use css files. I need to write a single HTML file.
Thank you,

Answer (score 0):

This is impossible.

HTML is not a graphics language, and was never designed to be.

HTML has certain features that can be abused to fake the drawing of graphics, but none of them were introduced as early as HTML 2 (which doesn't support any kind of border specification).

Comment: Is this situation same for HTML 3.2, and do you have any suggestions on ways how something can be achieved (same or similar) in HTML 2?

Comment: HTML 3.2 introduces tables which allow for some horrible hacks to simulate drawing. I would fix the underlying problem and use something designed for handling images if images are needed.

Answer (score 0):

There's a way to add internal css files:

```
 <html>
 <head>
 <Title>Rectangle</Title>
 </head>
 <body>
 <div class="rectangle_style">

 </div>
 <style type="text/css"> 
 .rectangle_style {

 position: relative;
 top: 100px;
 left: 600px;
 width: 100px;
 height: 50px;
 display: table;
 border: 2px solid #000;
 background: #0AC6EC;

 }
 </style>

 </body>
 </html>
```

Modify the "style" element to adapt the rectangle